# Skype not making incoming call sound

Tags: 11.10, skype

This happens only when I get a call. If someone calls me there is absolutely no sound at all. No "someone is calling me" sound. If I call someone I do hear the sound of calling (The cool skype calling sound). I went to the sound configuration in Skype and the **Make a test sound** button did not "MAKE" a sound.

Am using 2.2.0.35 from Software Center.

Comment: I have the same issue, when someone calls skype does not ring, so if I am away from my screen I will miss those calls.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found the problem. I normally deactivate the Alert Sound in Ubuntu since I like it to be silent. The problem is that for the incoming sound to "sound" you need to have Alert Volume without mute, preferably maxed.

[image]

After unchecking the mute option it started sounding again.

So basically go to the Sound Setting and change that. It worked in my case. The problem now is telling Ubuntu with another option to disable all the animal sounds it makes when opening, closing windows and and starting Ubuntu or shutting it down.

Comment: It is a known bug/feature: jira.skype.com/browse/SCL-658

Comment: Thank you. Yes this was solved at least a month after I posted. Right now I am using the 4.x version of Skype which works great.